# Combining corresponding columns between two separate dataframes into new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes looking like below:

```py
df1

Column 1   Column 2  Column 3 
0.2         0.4       0.5 
0.25        0.44      0.45 
0.26        0.32      0.33

df2

Column 1   Column 2  Column 3 
340         350       360
410         400       350
234         324       450
```

How can I combine `df1` and `df2` to make a dataframe `df3` that has Columns of the same # side-by-side, i.e.

```py
df3 
Column 1  Column 1  Column 2  Column 2  Column 3  Column 3
0.2         340       0.4       350      0.5       360
0.25        410       0.44      400      0.45      350 
0.26        234       0.32      324      0.33      450
```

Thank you!

Comment: Something like `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: This makes the number of rows twice as large, and so half the elements in each column are N/A

Comment: It can happen if your indexes are not the same. What if you do `df1.index = df2.index` before calling `concat`?

Comment: another option (thought not as classic as concat) 

pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

Answer (score 1):

To alternate the columns for any dataframe (with any, possibly non-identical column names), first combine the two dataframes and then reorder them by passing a list of column names in the order that you want.

For alternating order, first get lists of the two dataframe column names

```
l1 = df1.columns
l2 = df2.columns
```

Then create pairs of column names zipping them the two lists (results in `('col1','col1')`.... ect.)

```
colNames = zip(l1, l2)
```

Then combine in an alternating fashion with list comprehension

```
combinedNames = [name for pair in colNames for name in pair]
```

This will create a list with paired columns names.

Apply this list to your combined dataframe to reorder it:

```
combinedDf = combinedDf[combinedNames]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do that is by defining a new DataFrame and using the pandas.DataFrame.append() function in a for loop so that you alternate the 2 DataFrames. Then you need to transform your new DataFrame to get it right:

```
NumColumn=d1.shape[1]

NewDF = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(NumColumn):
  NewDF = NewDF.append(d1.iloc[:, i])
  NewDF = NewDF.append(d2.iloc[:, i])


NewDF = NewDF.T
```